# MeteorJS: Dummy for user and its roles to do unit testing

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, meteor

I would like to do some unit testing (mocha/chai) for my meteor application. I'm using validated methods (which shouldn't matter for this).

In my method I'm checking if the user has admin permission to perform a collection update.

How do I set a 'dummy' in my unit test, as right now the test will always fail with a 403 error throw.

**Unit test**

```
describe('method', () => {
  it('should update document', (done) => {
    articleUpdate.call({ _id, value })
  }
})
```

**Method**

```
const articleUpdate = new ValidatedMethod({
  name: 'article.update',
  validate: null,

  run ({ _id, value }) {
    const loggedInUser = Meteor.user()
    const isAdmin = Roles.userIsInRole(loggedInUser, ['group'], 'admin')

    if (!isAdmin) { throw new Meteor.Error(403, 'Access denied') }

    Articles.update(_id, {
      $set: { content: value }
    })
  }
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In test mode you can use `_execute` to execute a validated method to pass a context, see [here](https://github.com/meteor/validated-method#method_executecontext-object-args-object). However, the easiest thing here seems to stub `Roles.userIsInRole` like so:

```
import { sandbox } from 'sinon';

const sb = sandbox.create();
describe('method', () => {
  it('should update document', () => {
    sb.stub(Roles, 'userIsInRole').callsFake(() => true);
    articleUpdate.call({ _id, value })
  }
})
```

Comment: I do get the error `Error: Attempted to wrap userIsInRole which is already wrapped`